# Pandas on Spark apply() seems to be reshaping columns

Tags: pyspark, aggregate, pyspark-pandas

Can anybody explain the following behavior?

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps

loan_information = ps.read_sql_query([blah])

loan_information.shape
#748834, 84

loan_information.apply(lambda col: col.shape)
#Each column has 75 dimensions. The first 74 are size 10000, the last is size 8843
#This still sums to 748834, but hardly seems like desirable behavior
```

My guess is that batches of size 10000 are being fed to the executors but, again, this seems like pretty undesirable behavior.

Comment: what is your desirable behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest//api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#:%7E:text=when%20axis%20is%200%20or%20%E2%80%98index%E2%80%99%2C%20the%20func%20is%20unable%20to%20access%20to%20the%20whole%20input%20series.%20pandas%2Don%2DSpark%20internally%20splits%20the%20input%20series%20into%20multiple%20batches%20and%20calls%20func%20with%20each%20batch%20multiple%20times.%20Therefore%2C%20operations%20such%20as%20global%20aggregations%20are%20impossible.%20See%20the%20example%20below.) is quite clear:

> when axis is 0 or ‘index’, the func is unable to access to the whole input series. pandas-on-Spark internally splits the input series into multiple batches and calls func with each batch multiple times. Therefore, operations such as global aggregations are impossible. See the example below.

[`.apply`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest//api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) is for non-aggregation functions, if you want to do aggregate type functions, use something like [`.aggregate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest//api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html#pyspark-pandas-dataframe-aggregate)

Comment: thanks Bert! Didn't see that in the docs